# Ruby 3 Rails 7 Solr 9 docker-compose Can't reindex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker-compose, solr

In my project, I have encountered the reindex problems with Ruby 3 Rails 7 Solr 9(use Sunspot gem)

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password

  solr:
    image: solr:9.3.0
    ports:
      - "8983:8983"
    volumes:
      - search-data:/opt/solr/server/solr/mycores
    entrypoint:
      - docker-entrypoint.sh
      - solr-precreate
      - development
    depends_on:
      - db

  app:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails assets:precompile && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - bundle:/usr/local/bundle
      - tmp-data:/app/tmp
      - public-data:/app/public
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - solr

volumes:
  bundle:
  tmp-data:
  public-data:
  search-data:
```

My `config/sunspot.yml`

```yaml
production:
  solr:
    hostname: solr
    solr_home: solr
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/production
    # read_timeout: 2
    # open_timeout: 0.5

development:
  solr:
    hostname: solr
    solr_home: solr
    port: 8983
    log_level: INFO
    path: /solr/development

test:
  solr:
    hostname: solr
    solr_home: solr
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/test
```

When I run the `rake sunspot:solr:start` in the `app` container:

```
# rake sunspot:solr:start
rake aborted!
Sunspot::Solr::Server::JavaMissing: You need a Java Runtime Environment to run the Solr server
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sunspot_solr-2.6.0/lib/sunspot/solr/java.rb:11:in `ensure_install!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sunspot_solr-2.6.0/lib/sunspot/solr/server.rb:27:in `initialize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sunspot_solr-2.6.0/lib/sunspot/solr/tasks.rb:38:in `new'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sunspot_solr-2.6.0/lib/sunspot/solr/tasks.rb:38:in `server'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sunspot_solr-2.6.0/lib/sunspot/solr/tasks.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
Tasks: TOP => sunspot:solr:start
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

When I run the `rake sunspot:solr:reindex`

```
# rake sunspot:solr:reindex
rake aborted!
RSolr::Error::Http: RSolr::Error::Http - 400 Bad Request
Error: undefined field type

URI: http://solr:8983/solr/development/update?wt=json
Request Headers: {"Content-Type"=>"text/xml"}
Request Data: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><delete><query>type:Album</query></delete>"
...
```

Can anyone help me what additional configs must I add?

Answer (score -1):

Error message clearly indicates that Java is not installed, while executing solar start command.

Comment: I understand what you mean. The thing is the container that has Java environment is the Solr container, not the Rails container. Is there anyway to config the sunspot gem into using the Java on Solr search engine?